# Something wrong with the Peterson algorithm logic?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, locking

I am pretty new to Multithreading programming. In my code threads are trying to acquire locks around few lines. The lines work pretty fine for few context switches but then it halts (probably a deadlock).

On the other hand if use `synchronized` block then all works fine.

I've four classes.

**1. PetersonAlgorithm.java**

```
package com.ashish.master;

public class PetersonAlgorithm {

    boolean wantCS[] = {false, false};
    int turn = 1;

    public void requestCS(int i) {
        System.out.println("Lock requested by the thread - " + i);
        wantCS[i] = true;
        turn = 1 - i;
        while(wantCS[1-i] && turn == 1-i);

    }

    public void releaseCS (int i) {
        wantCS[i] = false;
        turn = i - 1;
        System.out.println("Lock released by the thread - " + i);
    }

}
```

If anyone feels that above algorithm is incorrect then let me know, and feel free to make suggestions.

**2. Runner.java**

```
package com.ashish.master;

public class Runner {

    public static Incrementer runnableInstance = new Incrementer();
    public static Thread inc1 = new Thread(runnableInstance, "0");
    public static Thread inc2 = new Thread(runnableInstance, "1");

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        inc1.start();
        inc2.start();

        try{
            inc1.join();
            inc2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("The threads have been interrupted while waiting for the join ---> " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("The total turns taken by incrementer are ----> " + runnableInstance.turns);

    }

}
```

**3. Incrementer.java** - *If `synchronized` block is used instead of the Peterson algorithm, everything works fine.*

```
package com.ashish.master;

public class Incrementer implements Runnable {

    public long turns = 0;
    public PetersonAlgorithm pa = new PetersonAlgorithm();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Thread " + this.toString() + "started.....");
        while(true) {
            pa.requestCS(Integer.parseInt(this.toString()));
//          synchronized(this) {
                if(DataStore.data < 1000000) printCriticalSection();
                else break;
//          }
            pa.releaseCS(Integer.parseInt(this.toString()));
        }

    }

    public void printCriticalSection() {
        System.out.println("The value of the number is increased by thread " +
                this.toString() +" to --> " + DataStore.increase());
            turns ++;       
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

}
```

**4. DataStore.java** *A class to mock the data source -- simply increase the number*

```
package com.ashish.master;

public class DataStore {

    public static long data = 0L;

    public static long increase() {
        DataStore.data += 1;
        return DataStore.data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your runnables never observe each other's monitors (wantCS and turn) as they have different instances... Each runnable needs to work with a same shared set of monitors!

Take the blue pill and make your PetersonAlgorithm variables static volatile with synchronized block access...

Or take the red pill and you create a Class for your flag monitors (wantCS) and for your indicator monitor (turn). Then just define your runnable with one "own flag", one "observed flag" and one "indicator". Both Runnables will have the same indicator instance (therefore needs to be synchronized) while the flag instances will be crossed (the own flag of R1 will be the observed flag of R2 and the own flag of R2 the observed flag of R1). You should synchronized the flag methods too as you don't want to have a flag raised or lowered while being observed.

Then few steps:

1. Runnables raise their Flag
2. Runnables turn the shared Indicator ( set to opponent runnable's id )
3. Wait if opponent's flag is raised and Indicator is set to opponent.
4. The non waiting opponent does its stuff then lowers its flag.
5. The waiting opponent stops waiting (opponent's flag has been lowered), does its stuff and lowers its flag.

Comment: I will take the red pill. :D And if I could digest it and it solves my problem I would accept your answer. Definitely. :)

Comment: ;) If you have any questions, don't hesitate!

Answer (score 0):

Each of your runnable instances has its own PetersonAlgorithm instance. Thus, the two runnables don't know anything about each other and will both always get immediate access to the critical section. Try implementing your PetersonAlgorithm class as `static` class with `static` methods. Then change the lines

```
pa.requestCS(Integer.parseInt(this.toString()));
// ...
pa.releaseCS(Integer.parseInt(this.toString()));
```

into

```
PetersonAlgorithm.requestCS(Integer.parseInt(this.toString()));
// ...
PetersonAlgorithm.releaseCS(Integer.parseInt(this.toString()));
```

Comment: No making PetersonAlgorithm class as `static` class with `static` methods doesn't work. **Reason-** both my thread are created with only one `Runnable` instance. Following lines [5 - 7] in **Runner.java** show it- `
 public static Incrementer runnableInstance = new Incrementer();
 public static Thread inc1 = new Thread(runnableInstance, "0");
 public static Thread inc2 = new Thread(runnableInstance, "1");
`